# The products is not listing in app.component.html

Tags: angular

I am trying to list the product in an HTML. But the record is not being showed and at the same time the the product list can be seen in JavaScript message. Please  somebody can help me to  list the record in an html file . Here is my code
in app.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Skinet';
  products: any[]=[];
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/products').subscribe((Response: any) => {
      
      this.products = Response.data;
      console.log(Response.data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

}
```

In app.component.html

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 140px;">
    <h1>Welcomes to {{title}}!</h1>
    <ul>
        asd
        <li class="list-unstyled" *ngFor="let product of products">  <!-- the Product is not coming -->
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: What does the console log for Response.data show exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not displaying anything from the productList.

```
<ul>
    asd
    <li class="list-unstyled" *ngFor="let product of products">
       {{product.<attributeName>}}
    </li>

</ul>
```

Additional Recommendations

1. Use an Interface or Class `products: ProductInfo[] = [];`. TypeScript allows your JavaScript code to be strongly typed. Take advantage of that feature. Can save you tons of debug time.
2. Move http calls to a service. 'Single Responsibility rule. Keep your component code a simple and short as possible. It should do one thing and one thing well. Plus it helps with delegation of duties in your project.

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: When I add <attributeName> , The error , it is not known element

Comment: You wont actually add <attributeName> that is a placeholder and needs to be updated with an attribute in the Product Object. Can you provide what your product object looks like?

Comment: I given  the attribute        {{product.ProductName}} still not working